# Change mouse velocity with pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am trying to automate a game using pyautogui but I was trying to change the mouse velocity but I couldn't find a way so is there a way? I mean like to look behind you and thanks in forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modified example from  the [Automate the boring stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/)

```py
import pyautogui
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration=0.10*i)
    pyautogui.moveTo(200, 100, duration=0.10*i)
    pyautogui.moveTo(200, 200, duration=0.10*i)
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200, duration=0.10*i)
```

There is `duration` parameter in the [`moveTo()`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html?highlight=moveto#mouse-movement) function that you can use to control the speed of the mouse. The unit of `duration` is seconds.